# XLWings - app.display_alerts = False not suppressing bad formula error message

Tags: python, xlwings

I am using Python `3.8.3` and XLWings `0.19.5`. I am trying to write a `try...catch` while running excel equations directly in a workbook, but equations with certain errors are causing the application to hang. I think this is due to a message box popping up.

```
import xlwings as xw

appExcel = xw.apps.add()
appExcel.display_alerts = False
appExcel.screen_updating = False

wbEquation = xw.Book()
wbEquation.sheets.add(name='Calculate')
wsEquation = wbEquation.sheets['Calculate']

badFormula = "=A1+(A2+A3"

 try:
    wsEquation.range('B1').formula = badFormula
 except Exception:
    appExcel.quit()
    raise Exception("There was an error when running the equation.")
```

With `display_alerts=False` I am not sure why it is getting hung on the `wsEquation.range('B1').formula = badFormula` line, I believe due to a `There is a problem with a formula` error. On the older version of `XLWings 0.10.0` I was running it does not get hung up and moves past the error message when I try and execute this equation.

*Edit: So I tested to see [which version](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html) exactly breaks it and I was able to keep it working through `0.11.5`. Upgrading to `0.11.6` broke it. I do not see anything in the [release notes](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-11-6-jan-27-2018) between the two versions suggesting why that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for right now I am fixing by rolling back to `0.11.5`:

```
pip install "XLWings==0.11.5"
```

I have put in a bug report: [link](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1409) and it was marked as a `bug` so I think they will be working on it.